# Hold row for 4 minutes then delete if no action is taken

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm building a reservation system using php/mysql and I'm trying to figure out how to hold a row for 4 minutes while the end user inputs their detailed information for the reservation to avoid people reserving the same ticket at the same time. If they leave the page, the record "holding" that ticket will be deleted once the 4 minute timer ends.

I've been thinking about scheduling an event to run 4 minutes after they hit the initial page, but when they complete the information page and finalize their reservation that event should be cancelled. I've searched a lot on this issue and only found ways to schedule future events not "hold" a record.

I also thought maybe create a unique temporary value that I could have an event look for at the end of 4 minutes (i.e. a varchar with `'DELETE4MINS'` in a name column). However, I feel like there should be a better way to do this and none of the rows dealing with reserved tickets have varchar elements.

I have the following tables holding ticket reservation info:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations(
    rid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    aid int NOT NULL,
    approval tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    creationTime TIMESTAMP 
        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (rid),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_RESERVATION_COMPOSITE UNIQUE(rid, approval),
    FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES accounts (aid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE reservedTickets(
    rid int NOT NULL,
    tid int NOT NULL,
    hid int NOT NULL,
    approval tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tid),
    FOREIGN KEY (rid, approval) REFERENCES reservations (rid, approval)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES tickets (tid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES people (hid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally do not see any reason for actually deleting the entry. Basically all you have to do is create a reservation in the DB with the current time stamp when the user asks for one. Upon success you will present them some kind of a timer (using JS) that will show them the remaining time. And when the user submits the form the only thing you have to do is to compare current time to the time stamp in the DB and throw an error in case it has already been more than 4 minutes. If, for some reason, you do want to delete the entry, you will probably need to run a CRON job that will run every n minutes and delete all the "expired" rows. Or, in the very worst case, you can perform that operation every time someone accesses the service (and it will be part of the page code), although it's a bad idea.

EDIT: You can perform the delete query on the page that displays all the tickets. The flow will be as follows: as soon as someone accesses the page with the list of tickets, all the expired entries get deleted and you show them unreserved tickets only. This will ensure that people can only see those that are accessible, yet not expired

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid a cron job if possible. I know I could run one every 5 minutes or so and delete expired entries. However, I'd prefer to keep it embedded in the SQL for my own sanity's sake. Separation of concerns

Comment: The reason why the row needs to be deleted is that the frontend displays tickets that are approved and pending in the system. If the row holding the tickets is not deleted nobody else will be able to request that ticket until it is cleared. There's usually 200-300 people simultaneously trying to reserve 30-40 tickets and turnaround is very important.

Comment: In that case performing the delete action every time someone's accessing the page is a way to go. It may affect performance though. There are also other workarounds such as running a separate page that refreshes itself every 4 minutes and deletes all the rows but that is even worse

Comment: Fortunately I heavily overprovisioned this server 12GB RAM and 6 cores to handle the concurrent access. Performance shouldnt be a huge issue. However, that takes me back to the original question of how can I schedule that delete operation if no action is taken within 4 minutes.

Comment: I don't really see any way of doing it on the client's side. You can add some JS code that will redirect them to a page that will perform the delete operation but they can have their javascript disabled. So my guess would be to perform the delete query on the page that displays all the tickets. The flow will be as follows: as soon as someone accesses the page with the list of tickets, all the expired entries get deleted and you show them unreserved tickets only. This will ensure that people can only see those that are accessible, yet not expired

Comment: That is a beautiful solution, I wouldn't have thought to leverage the other clients to handle the delete operation. Please update your above answer so I can accept it as the solution.